# Button not working with HTML and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, button

I am trying to make some buttons and they do not work. I am very sure that I have done everything correct with the buttons. I am thinking it might have something to do with the Javascript functions they call, therefore I have added that part of my code aswell.
If you would like to see my full code, go to Github on my profile TheNumnut under Wars-Of-Shares.

```
<button onclick="buyshare()">Buy Share</button>
<button onclick="OpenTab("https://thenumnut.github.io/Wars-of-Shares/Profile")">Profile</button>

<script>
function buyshare() {
  shares ++;
  setCookie("shares", shares, 365);
  alert("You have " + shares + " shares");
  window.open("https://thenumnut.github.io/Wars-of-Shares/Market");
}

function OpenTab(x) {
  window.open("https://thenumnut.github.io/Wars-of-Shares/Profile");
</script>
```

If anybody can solve my problem I will much appreciate it. My full code is attached on the link: https://github.com/TheNumnut/Wars-of-Shares/blob/master/Market/index.html

**UPDATE:**
The button does open a new link and alerts. However, it will say: "You have NaN shares". And whenever I click it, it will not add one to shares.

Comment: You forgot a `}` at the end of your `OpenTab` function. Your browser's developer console will tell you this (or at least that the error's around that line), incidentally.

Comment: But it doesn't add 1 to shares. Thank you, it now opens the new tab and alerts.

Comment: So, do some debugging. Right now, it says you've got NaN shares. Not-a-number. Find where you're setting shares to a non-number and fix it.

Comment: It appears you are right, however when I used parseInt it did not work. It still said Nan Shares. Please check my github.

Comment: Of course it doesn't work. When the user comes to your page, there's no cookie yet. No initial value, so your `getCookie` returns `""`. Is that a number? Programming won't go well if you won't do some troubleshooting. `console.log` out variable values at different points to make sure they're what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem 1:** Your button `onClick` uses 4 quotes. Instead of doing

```
onclick="OpenTab("https://thenumnut.github.io/Wars-of-Shares/Profile")"
```

either escape the quotes using `\"` in place of `"` or use `'`.

**Problem 2:** Your JS function `OpenTab()` is missing a closing curly bracket.

**Problem 3:** Your variable `shares` is not a number. You are getting the integer portion of the `return` value of `setCookie()`, which does not return any values. (I don't see how setting cookies relates to shares, either). Add a `return yourValueHere` or set it manually.

Comment: Go to my Github. What you said is assuming that is my full code which it isn't. Please have a look at my Github.

Comment: I did. I originally had more issues but removed them as seeing they're not an issue in the full code. Also, next time post only the full code. The excerpt is misleading considering it's missing a few parts.